# Disable module and it's output programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, configuration, magento-2.0

In magento 1 disable module and it's output programmatically

```
protected function _disableModule($moduleName) {
    // Disable the module itself
    $nodePath = "modules/$moduleName/active";
    if (Mage::helper('core/data')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) {
        Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePath, 'false', true);
    }

    // Disable its output as well (which was already loaded)
    $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig($outputPath)) {
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig($outputPath, true);
    }
}
```

How can I do same in magento 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable a module itself, you need to use `Magento\Framework\Module\Status` class:

```
$status = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Module\Status');
$status->setIsEnabled(false,[$moduleName]);
```

To disable the module output, you need to use `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config` via the factory `Magento\Config\Model\ConfigFactory`:

```
$outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";
$config = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config');
$config->saveConfig($outputPath,true,'default',0);
```

In the line, `default` corresponds to the scope and `0` to the scope id. Those values will have to be changed depending on your needs.

**N.B. : this code is provided as a quick example, try to avoid using the object manager directly and use dependency injection to use those classes**

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not working saveConfig have 4 argument 'saveConfig($path, $value, $scope, $scopeId)' you have mentioned only 2. It gives error argument missing.

Comment: @PrashantValanda see my updated code.

Comment: `$this->objectManager->get` should be `$this->objectManager->create`  because it is working for me with `$this->objectManager->create`

Comment: @PrashantValanda I've updated the code ;)

Comment: why this is possible when we can disable modules with config.php and push it with git  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can using block method,

i have given demo for wishlist,
you can change any module using replace `Magento_Wishlist` to your required module in setConfigvalue parameter 1.

```
class Custom{
    protected $resourceConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    }


    protected function setConfigValue($pathId, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)
    {
        $this->resourceConfig->saveConfig($pathId, $value, $scope, $scopeId);
    }

    /**
     * Disable module's functionality for case when new relic extension is not available
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function disableModule()
    {
        $this->setConfigValue('advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Wishlist', 1);
    }

}
```